# How to create a matrix of data migration?

Tags: r, migration, markov-chains

Suppose we start with this dataframe, and R-code that generates it immediately below:

```
> data
   ID Period Values Flags
1   1      1      5    X0
2   1      2     10    X1
3   1      3     15    X2
4   1      4     20    X3
5   2      1      0    X0
6   2      2      2    X2
7   2      3      4    XO
8   2      4      6    X1
9   3      1      3    XO
10  3      2      6    XO
11  3      3      9    X2
12  3      4     12    XO

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 12),
    Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X3","X0","X2","XO", "X1", "XO","XO","X2","XO")
  )
```

I am trying to generate code that shows the migration of the number of ID's (and Values by number of ID's) from one "Flag" category to the next, based on the 2 periods input by the user. So for example, if the user inputs period 1 as the "from" period and period 4 as the "to" period, we'd get the migration tables as shown in the image at the bottom. I also include 2/3 from/to on the right side of the image, for sake of illustration.

I've typically done this sort of analysis in Excel, a cumbersome multi-step process, and am now trying it out in R.

Any suggestions for coding this?
[image]

Comment: Is it meaningful that you have both `X0` and `XO` in your data?

Comment: from period 2 to 3: why to_flag = X2 if from_flag = x1 and value = 10? You need 3 columns from_flag, to_flag and value to make this pivot table on the right. You only got 2 columns flags and values. Why is there even column ID?

Comment: Hi r2evans - X0 and XO are meant to be the same (X0), that was a typo on my part.

Comment: Hi danlooo - for ID=1, period 2 [value is 10 and flag is X1] and period 3 [flag is X2]; so I show a migration from X1 to X2, for an event count of 1 and a value of 10 (value of 10 migrated from X1 to X2, from period 2 to 3). I agree the ID isn't strictly necessary. ID identifies an individual element, with period indicating time horizon and Values/Flags showing different measures of how that element evolves over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are functions to create the two required tables.

Note that you had a problem with X0 and XO in your mock data set as r2evans already suggested (I've transformed everything to X0).

```
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 12),
    Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X3","X0","X2","X0", "X1", "X0","X0","X2","X0")
  )

generateTable <- function(data){
  df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=length(unique(data$Flags)), nrow=length(unique(data$Flags))))
  row.names(df) <- unique(data$Flags)
  names(df) <- unique(data$Flags)
  return(df)
}

numbers2migrate <- function(data, from=1, to=4){
  df <- generateTable(data)
  for (i in unique(data$ID)){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(df) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(df) == id_to)
    df[row, column] <- ifelse(is.na(df[row, column]), 1, df[row, column] + 1)
  }
  return(df)
}

values2migrate <- function(data, from=1, to=4){
  df <- generateTable(data)
  for (i in unique(data$ID)){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(df) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(df) == id_to)
    
    val <- (data$Values[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    df[row, column] <- val
  }
  return(df)
}


> numbers2migrate(data, from=1, to=4)
   X0 X1 X2 X3
X0  1 NA NA NA
X1  1 NA NA NA
X2 NA NA NA NA
X3  1 NA NA NA
> values2migrate(data,1,4)
   X0 X1 X2 X3
X0  3 NA NA NA
X1  0 NA NA NA
X2 NA NA NA NA
X3  5 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Hi JKupzig, I'm going through this code now. THANK YOU! Works nicely. Do you think one of the apply() functions would work here and be preferable over the for-loop? The actual data this will be used for has 2.5m rows, 30 columns or so. In other usage instances I could see 5m or so rows. I wonder if a vectorized apply() family approach would work better when deployed on more data.

Comment: Hey Curious Jorge, when performance is an issue a vectorize apply is an option to speed up the code. Also, you could use Rcpp to write the for loop in c++ if you are familiar with it. I've thought because the task was done in excel before that performance would not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, done in Excel before and it was a horrendously manual task of breaking it down into pieces (using SQL in conjunction with Excel actually), then cobbling the pieces back together for migration results. This R solution will be much better